# How can I Speed up Mysql query using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Webapp that has one function that is slow.

I ask to suggest code to speed up this function from 5-6 seconds to 1-2 seconds.

I have database with tables:

table: Workers (id, ﬁrst_name, last_name)

table: Stores (id, name)

table: worker_store (id, worker_id, store_id)

The idea is that workers are connected to a single or multiple stores via worker_store table.

In Laravel app I have a function that takes a single store and shows that workers are connected to this particular store. This must be displayed as “select” ﬁeld with connected workers marked as “selected” and all other workers as not selected. My Laravel blade code look like this

```
<select multiple name="workers[]" id="workers" class="form-control">
 @foreach (App\Worker::orderBy('last_name')->get() as $worker)                               
  <option value="{{$worker->id}}" 
  **@if ($object->hasWorker($worker->id))                                    
   selected @endif**>{{$worker->getName()}}
  </option>           
@endforeach  


</select>
```

Database is MySQL and worker table has 30,000 records. It is very slow while laravel makes 30 000 separate queries to the database to check every worker if he is linked to a particular store (bold part of code above).

Please suggest a solution that doesn't need to query 30 000 times database and make generation of full  in no more than 1-2 seconds (current code takes about 5-6 seconds).

Comment: Show the code you are using which queries the workers.  Also take a look here...  https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: mycode is there in my Question

Comment: @Guanapado Pado why don't you use Datatable and laravel paginate. here the examples which can help you implement in your project.
[https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables]
[https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/post.html]
[https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a lot to put in the view but here's the basic concept of what I think you are looking for...

```
// Grab all the workers so that we can loop through them.
$workers = App\Worker::all();

// Grab a list of the worker id's for the store we are currently searching for.
$storeWorkers = App\Store::with('workers')->find(1)->workers->lists('id');

// Use in_array to determine if the worker is currently working in the store we are looking at.
@foreach ($workers as $worker)
    <option value="{{ $worker->id }}" {{ in_array($worker->id, $storeWorkers) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $worker->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

This should net you a total of 3 queries.  1 to grab all the workers and 2 to grab the workers by store.

It would seem your models are not setup correctly.  In your `Store` model, add the function...

```
public function workers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Worker::class, 'worker_store');
}
```

Comment: Thnx, I will try your suggested code and see if it works.

Comment: as i understand $workers .... and $storeWorkers ... shall go to controller 
and @foreach to blade template

Comment: Yeah that would probably be best

Comment: PLEASE HELP OUT I need to figure out where to put it, because now i get error 
Call to a member function lists() on null
i'm quite a newby so i need some time to figure out :)  CAN I PASTE MY CONTROLLER SO THAT YOU CAN EASILY FIGURE OUT HOW TO PUT THESE QUERIES AS EXACT. It will be helpfull for me.

Comment: If that code is being hit, I don't think the controller would help.  Did you swap out the 1 with the actual id of the store in question?

Comment: i have not replaced 1 in question but o trigger another way, this i fixed
but now i get all to undefined method Sofa\Eloquence\Query\Builder::workers()

Comment: I've modified my answer.

Comment: Can you Please help me about a laravel socialite plugin.I have put a question but not a single person replied to that.Can you please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39425687/laravel-socialite-doesnt-take-get-parameter-to-redirect-on-same-page for reference and reply there.I will be thankfull to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should re think how you made this application.

It makes no usable sense to have 30k options in a select, who is going to go through 30k options of the select checking in and out the options? Who would even read those options?
It makes no sense, is an application that is not possible to use. And why would you make an application that no one can use?

First you need to think of the problem, then on how to solve the problem, how your solution will actually help someone to solve the problem, instead of causing a more complicated problem. Throwing all the data out is not a solution for anything.

You probably should think of a AJAX/React/Vue.js or similar front end thing that allows the user to have an interaction with the data in terms that makes sense.

But, that takes time, so, you may at least solve it quickly by creating instead a page where you could filter workers based on name or something, then, and use pagination, each option having a checkbox next to it, indicating if is selected or not and allowing to select additionals, or instead of a checkbox a color or icon that indicate the current status and a button to add/remove it.

That way the user can search for the options it wants, navigate things, change things in a more suitable and doable way.

**Note:** also, make sure you have indexes in your database in every column that relates to other data, every column that you order, every column that you use to filter.

**Your problem is not as much the query, as it is the massive amount of data that you are throwing in the HTML**

Comment: Sir It is actually solved now I get the result in 0.8 seconds and it was done by following the procedure defined by user3158900 above but now i have a problem with laravel socialite plugin.can you please help me.Can you Please help me about a laravel socialite plugin.I have put a question but not a single person replied to that.Can you please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39425687/laravel-socialite-doesnt-take-get-parameter-to-redirect-on-same-page for reference and reply there.I will be thankfull to you

Comment: very good point in bold: "the massive amount of data that you are throwing in the HTML"

if you havent run into this before, it can cripple your site and force you to re-architect everything... so be aware of how much data might be showing up in future . . . . .